# If i take Lambert W function, does it changes the inequality sign?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am solving an inequality which contain log term and i solved it by using Lambert function. When I replaces Y with W(y) do i need to change the sign of inequality or it will remain same? plz help

Comment: You should give more details about your question if you want to get good answers.